# Rails where query with localization date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How can I get an ActiveRecord with the specific I18n locale.

As if I want to do:

```
users = User.where(name: "John"), locale: :es
```

But when this return will be in the `:es` locale format.

Comment: Could you please show me your expected outputs?

Comment: Sure. This for example - "Viernes, julio 21, 2017". But if it will be locale: :en it will be - "Friday, July 21, 2017".
The date formats I will set in the en.yml and es.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set before the locale, and then use the I18n.localize, wrapping your data as the argument:

As an example:

```
User.last.created_at
# Sun, 15 Apr 2018 04:20:05 UTC +00:00
```

Setting the locale:

```
I18n.locale = :es
I18n.localize(User.last.created_at)
# "Dom, 15 Abr 2018 04:20:05 +0000"
```

`I18n.localize` can be shortened as `I18n.l`, while working in views, you can simply use `l`.

You might also want to look at the [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).